Al consumir distance matrix retorna sin datos
Recurro a este lugar porque no encuentro una respuesta lógica a un fallo en la solicitud desde visual studio code a la api de distance matriz me manda el resultado de la petición vacío. Este es mi código de petición y tuve que poner el no cord porque me marcaba error en la solicitud


const requestOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=parres,tlapan&origins=san andres,tlalpan&units=imperial&key=AIzaSyA5hUBmtdk-dy63sf10Uh-FsW6e7jACcBY", requestOptions)
  .then((response) => response.text())
  .then((result) => console.log(result))
  .catch((error) => console.error(error));




Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! vs code es una ide.. habras hecho la peticion desde algun lenguaje, supongo... hay un espacio ahi... seguro que eso esta mal.. pero re seguro.. pero recontra re seguro...

Hola Leidy, no publiques tus API Keys en sitios públicos. Te recomiendo cambiarla cuanto antes.

hola, que debemos hacer para reproducir el error???

los problema no estan en el codigo, estan en el contenido del fetch y pueden ser: credemciales de la api, permisos de la api, problema de cors.

@FranciscoNuñezIALover hay un espacio en la peticion get.. fin del tema por ese lado.. eso esta mal!

@FranciscoNuñezIALover se refiere al de san Andres?

pues supongo que si ... intenta con un nombre que no tenga espacios

hay te deje una respuesta de como yo lo implementaria.

si alguna de las respuesta te ha servido podes marcarla como resuelta, eso te dara al menos 2 puntos de reputacion que te seran utiles en un futuro. saludos.

por lo que veo tiene problemas con la url, yo intentaria hacerlo asi:


const origins = encodeURIComponent("san andres,tlalpan");
const destinations = encodeURIComponent("parres,tlapan");
const apiKey = "AIzaSyA5hUBmtdk-dy63sf10Uh-FsW6e7jACcBY"; // Recuerda reemplazar "tu_api_key" con tu propia clave API de Google

const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=${origins}&destinations=${destinations}&units=imperial&key=${apiKey}`;

const requestOptions = {
  method: "GET",
  redirect: "follow"
};

fetch(url, requestOptions)
  .then(response => console.log(response.text()))
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));



Entonces: como podras ver estoy implementando encodeURIComponent para obtener los fragmentos formateados necesarios para construir la url, esto codificara los nombres de las ubicaciones y asegura que los espacios u otros caracteres especiales sean manejados correctamente.
Ten en cuenta que en este sitio al darle click el fetch dara error por CORS ... debes probarlo en tu proyecto.
AS-IS: no tengo acceso a esa api para hacer pruebas... pero si entras a esta url de esta forma ya veras que hay un response:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=san%20andres%2Ctlalpan&destinations=parres%2Ctlapan&units=imperial&key=AIzaSyA5hUBmtdk-dy63sf10Uh-FsW6e7jACcBY

Tienes problemas de CORS, ese endpoint está pensado para usarse desde el servidor, para usar desde el cliente debes utilizar necesariamente la librería de google.
Además, necesitas configurar correctamente la API desde la consola de google, yo probé con la tuya y no funciona, pero al probar con una key antigua mía no hubo problema


function initMap() {
  const service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
  const request = {
    origins: ["san andres,tlalpan"],
    destinations: ["parres,tlapan"],
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL,
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false,
  };

  service.getDistanceMatrix(request).then(response => {
    //response ya está convertido a objeto, NO es necesario utilizar JSON.parse
  });
}
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=TU_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async></script>



Resultado usando una KEY personal:


Yussef ya lo hice pero tengo un problema en que no reconoce a google. y tengo una duda solo tengo que tener habilitada la api de distance matrix o hay otra que se requiera?

@LeidyRezaNoyola como te decía en mi respuesta, mi key es bastante vieja (del 2013) no recuerdo como la configuré. Lo que me aparece es que tengo estos servicios relacionados: https://i.sstatic.net/TpINfczJ.png intuyo que la necesaria es Maps JavaScript API dado que la Distance Matrix API no tiene solicitudes este mes (y yo para responderte efectivamente realicé al menos 2 de prueba)
